# Way to ID and blacklist users based of UDID on iOS ap

Tags: php, ios, uniqueidentifier, udid

Ok, I'll be brief, but some setup is required for this question.

My iOS app allows users to submit requests, which are then displayed via a Table View.  They fill out several text fields, and the text from those are passed along to a PHP script, which then adds entries to an XML.  I realize that some users could put phony entries in or inappropriate material.  What would be the best way to create a unique identifier based off of device, and attach it to the post?  Then, if inappropriate material appears, I can find the ID, and then use something in the script to disallow posts from users whose ID is in the database?

Just wondering how to set up the PHP and create an ID for the device.

Thanks

Comment: Using anything like phonegap?

Comment: I don't know what phonegap is, @Farkie

Comment: Its just a website not an actual app on the phone right?

Comment: No, it is an actual app.  Just like the OP says..."My iOS app allows users..."

Comment: So what's the question then?  The UID will come from the app and be sent to the PHP.  You don't generate the UID in PHP since PHP doesn't run on the iOS device.

Comment: @developerwjk once again, as is in the OP>....."What would be the best way to create a unique identifier based off of device, and attach it to the post?"

Comment: Then you should have tagged objective-C or whatever language you're using on the native side, right?

Comment: I don't know, @developerwjk I tagged iOS, I tagged unique identifier, I tagged UDID, and the title itself and question says iOS in it.  To me that would easily convey that this is an app I'm building using objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use one of `NSUUID`, `CFUUIDRef` or `UIDevice -unique​Identifier` / `-identifier​For​Vendor`. Check out this article for more: http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/